# Jax-rs client marshal list of entities using jax-b

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs

I need to marshal a list of entities using jax-b in a jax-rs client, without creating a wrapper class for each entity needed (there are manny entities!). I notice the service is able to marshal a list of customers like this:

```
<customers>
    <customer>.....</customer>
    <customer>.....</customer>
</customers>
```

Which I on the client side is able to unmarshal by finding all customer nodes and adding them to a list manually. (I guess there's a better way to do this?)

Now, the real problem here is when I want to send a list of an entity(eg. customers) to the service. I want to marshal this list into an xml string before writing this string as the payload of the request to the service. This does not work since java.util.List or its descendants is not known to the marshaller.

```
javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.marshal(list, StringWriter);
javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(org.​w3c.​dom.node)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!
-Runar

Edit:

Here's a snippet from the customer class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    .....
}
```

I'm trying to write a lightweight client using no 3rd party libraries not part of the standard implementation. Because of this I have written my own httpclient taking in payload objects, marhalling them and passing them to the payload of the request. When the response is received I read the xml and send it to unmarshalling. It would be awsome if I could do the marshalling/unmarshalling directly to/from string just as my jax-rs service does.

Comment: Please provide more of the code you use to marshal your list of objects.

Comment: hope this helps, if not please dont hesitate to request more  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found no good solution to this. But since it seems the pattern for my jax-rs service is to generate a root node called `<class name " + "s>`, I did this to be able to send lists of objects to the service:

```
if (obj instanceof List) {
    List list = (List) obj;
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        // Since the jax-b marshaller does not allow to send lists directly,
        // we must attempt to create the xml as the jax-rs service would expect them,
        // wrapped with the classname pluss an s.
        String wrapper = list.get(0).getClass().getSimpleName() + "s";
        // Make first letter in class-name lower-case
        wrapper = Character.toLowerCase(wrapper.charAt(0)) +
                  (wrapper.length() > 1 ? wrapper.substring(1) : "");
        marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        writer.write("<" + wrapper + ">");
        for (Object o : (List) obj) {
            marshaller.marshal(o, writer);
        }
        writer.write("</" + wrapper + ">");
    }
} else {
    marshaller.marshal(obj, writer);
}
```